# Do you have to wait for firebase hosting to "process" files before they're available?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm creating a react app with create react app and deploying to firebase hosting. I've done this several times, never without a hitch. But, many  of the assets in my public directory are giving 404 errors:

[image]

When I look at hosting in project console, it seems like the files are present:

[image]

I've pieced together online that files might only become available in Firebase Hosting after Firebase "processes" the files, is this the case? Someone suggested in [this thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Nb4.png) from the firebase forums that it might take some time before the assets become available.

Or maybe I've run up against some kind of limit with the free tier of firebase hosting?

Additional Info:

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It can take a few minutes for changes to show up and also make sure you clear your browser's cache.

Comment: Also, if you're doing dev on Windows or macOS but deploying to Linux then you might run-into issues with case-sensitivity (as NTFS, AFS, and HFS+ are case-insensitive but Linux's filesystems (`ext3`, `zfs`, etc) are case-sensitive, so if your video is located at `/videos/720/bach.mp4` (but your link is `/Videos/720/BACH.mp4`) then it will fail with a HTTP 404 error.